# How can i give Gaussian noise to my moons dataset with a deviation value of 0.2 in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have make_moons dataset, generated by scikit-learn

`X, y = make_moons(n_samples=120)`

How can i give Gaussian noise to my moons dataset with a deviation value of 0.2 in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass that value to the `make_moons` function as `noise`.

```
x, y = make_moons(n_samples=120, noise=0.2)
```

> noise : double or None (default=None)
> Standard deviation of Gaussian noise added to the data.